# Resolving merge conflicts when merging two repositories

Tags: git

I need to merge two large repositories into single repo. The problem is that both repositories have files that have same names, but are in different directories. When I'm merging, git discovers them as merge conflicts due to files being renamed or deleted (which is not true) and there are hundreds of them. I am looking for a way to resolve those conflicts in an easy way.

I want to have a single repository, which contains files from both smaller repos (and their history). Ideally I want them sorted like this:

- MainRepoDirectory/RepoA/all the files from RepoA here
- MainRepoDirectory/RepoB/all the files from RepoB here
- MainRepoDirectory/gitignore

Steps I have done already:

- Created MainRepo, then cloned it.
- `git checkout -b AddRepoA`
- `git remote add -f RepoA <url to RepoA>`
- `git merge RepoA/master --allow-unrelated-histories`
- Moved all files from RepoA to MainRepoDirectory/RepoA
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Added RepoA"`
- `git push origin AddRepoA -u`
- Merged AddRepoA to master on MainRepo
- `git checkout -b AddRepoB`
- `git remote add -f RepoB <url to RepoB>`
- `git merge RepoB/master --allow-unrelated-histories`

Last step produces hundreds of merge conflicts. Both repos are quite large and as I mentioned, they do contain files named the same way, but never in the same directories inside those repositories. Git should not discover them as renaming conflicts as those are not the same files. I want the merge to keep the old files intact, and add all the new ones.

Comment: Do the branches you are trying to merge have common ancestry?

Comment: No, just similar file names in similar, but at least partially different directories. For example both repoA/dirA/subDirX/theFile.cs and repoB/dirB/subDirX/theFile.cs can exist

Answer (score 1):

```
git merge RepoB/master --allow-unrelated-histories -Xno-renames
```

The merge strategy option `-Xno-renames` will prevent `git` from looking for renamed files and just treat files deletions/additions as such.
If that one doesn't work and renames still show up, try changing the merge strategy entirely by using `-s resolve` (thanks OP for the insight):

```
git merge RepoB/master --allow-unrelated-histories -s resolve
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not help

Comment: But you were close, `git merge -s resolve branchA --allow-unrelated-histories` did the job (I was on branch merge-branchA-to-branchB, created from branchB). Thanks for the help anyways. I'd upvote your answer, but unfortunatelly my account has too low reputation to do so.

Comment: @KacperStachowski Haha, all good. I'm glad to hear you were able to solve the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting it correctly (and maybe I am not because the use of git jargon is not correct in the question), you would like to have a *single* **branch** where you are *merging* the histories of 2 *unrelated* (from the ancestry POV) branches (even though it's like the same project with multiple differences between them) **and** you want to keep the exact contents of the tip of each one of the two branches you are trying to merge into separate directories of the final branch, did I get it right? If that's the case, this is what i would do:

```
git init experiment
cd experiment
git remote add repoA url-to-repo-A
git remote add repoB url-to-repo-B
git branch branchA repoA/some-branch-repo-A # created a local branch
git branch branchB repoB/some-branch-repo-B # another local branch
git checkout branchA
mkdir dirA
git mv * dirA # ask git to move everything to dirA
# check that there are no files left behind with ls -la
git commit -m "Moving everything from repoA/some-branch to dirA"
# same thing with the other branch
git checkout branchB
mkdir dirB
git mv * dirB # ask git to move everything to dirB
# check that there are no files left behind with ls -la
git commit -m "Moving everything from repoB/some-branch to dirB"
git checkout -b the-merge # creating a new branch for the merge
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories branchA
```

I would *expect* for git to not go crazy and just merge and give you the two directories the way you want.... *but* if that's not the case, you can simply force git to get you the two directories from the separate branches, regardless of what git thinks of what conflicts there are:

```
git restore --worktree --staged --source=branchA -- dirA # get dirA from what we have in branchA
git restore --worktree --staged --source=branchB -- dirB # get dirB from what we have in branchB
# at this point git should have nothing to complain about, no conflicts, no nothing.... check with git status
git commit "Merging both branches"
```

At this point, you should have a single history that merges the histories of both branches. And there should be no difference between yout dirA and branchA's dirA... and dirB and branchB's dirB. This can be checked with:

```
git diff branchA -- dirA
git diff branchB -- dirB
```

And now you can rename your branch `main` or `master` so that you keep this as the branch going forward... or something like that.

Comment: I would like to have a single branch where I am merging the histories of 2 unrelated (from the ancestry POV) branches, each from different repository. Each old branch contains one or more projects that are not related to each other, but do contain files that have the same names (but filenames are the only part of their path that can overlap).

Comment: I have followed your first suggestion, but still got merge conflits. Less than before, but still a lot of them. I ended up aborting the merge and, instead of using `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories branchA` I used `git checkout branchA -- dirA`. This got me where I wanted in the matter of having all the files in one place, but without any merge conflicts. The only problem left is that by doing it that way, I have lost all history from branchA. Since each branch contains everything from each repositories I wanted to merge, I need to preserve history of both of them.

Comment: They are not 2 recipes.... they are the same recipe.... **if there are conflicts** (as you are saying), then you need to use what is in the second part so that you get what each directory has from their branch and so there should be no more conflicts after you run the two `git checkout` commands... and then you can wrap up the merge by committing and _tadaaaaaa_, you have what you wanted.

Comment: I am replacing the checkouts for 2 restores in the recipe, by the way.

Comment: Thank you for your help. `git restore` did not help as well, as I still missed history from second branch. What ultimately helped me was using `git merge -s resolve branchA --allow-unrelated-histories` (I was on branch merge-branchA-to-branchB, created from branchB). Still, you gave me good directions. I'd upvote your answer, but unfortunatelly my account has too low reputation to do so.

Comment: How can you miss history from a branch during a merge? Anyway, as long as you were able to get what you want in a manner that makes sense to you, it's all good.