# Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history AND resolve conflicts

Tags: git, git-subtree

I need to combine two Git repositories into a third, new repository. Each original repository should be placed in a separate subfolder within the new repository. For instance, if I have repositories A and B, the directory structure of the third repository should look like this:

```
/root
   /repoA
      ...
   /repoB
      ...
```

It's important to note that all branches from repositories A and B should be transferred to the third repository.

I've identified a couple of methods to accomplish this:

1. Utilizing git subtree:

   - Initialize the third repository: `git init`
   - Add the remote for repository A: `git remote add repoA repo_url`
   - Integrate the subtree into a separate folder: `git subtree add --prefix repoA/ repo_url master`
   - Repeat this process for all branches.
2. Employing a script. For a more detailed explanation, you can refer to the verified answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history/).

However, I'm encountering issues when attempting to merge branches in the third repository. For instance, if I try to merge the `master` branch into `branchA`, a significant number of conflicts arise, which do not occur when merging `master` into `branchA` in repository A or B.

Comment: Does this answer your question or helps with finding a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76621289/resolving-merge-conflicts-when-merging-two-repositories/76621426